# Multiplayer game development in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, red5, multiplayer

Before you say that it is a repost of this question- [Alternatives to Flash Media Server for multiplayer game development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190802/alternatives-to-flash-media-server-for-multiplayer-game-development), it is slightly different as I am asking for pros and cons.

I want to know which server I should use for my specific flash game.
I am making a game called mathlympics. The idea is that the player has to answer simple arithmetic questions. The faster he answers the questions, the faster his athlete runs. I am making the game 3d using away3d engine for flash. A [similar 2d example can be seen here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIgIinS8hB8)

I want to make my game multiplayer, so that the different players could play against each other live at the same time.

Now I would like to know the pros and cons of the different engines.

- red5
- player.io
- amfPHP (suggested on this question - [AS3:Multiplayer Game by using AS3 with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691784/as3multiplayer-game-by-using-as3-with-php))
- spogg
- union

I do not which one is best. What are the pros and cons of each. Which one is easiest to use and which one suits my game best? If there are any other engines out there which might me more relevant to me, then please free to suggest?

Comment: Which one is easiest is rather subjective. Do you know Java, but not PHP? Then a Java solution would be easier for **you**, but maybe not someone else. It sounds like any server platform that allows real time communication will be sufficient for your game. I would choose 1 or 2 candidates and try doing something simple, then decide. Narrow your list by selecting things that: 1) use a language you are familiar with (or would like to learn) 2) fit your price point, 3) are mature and have a good user base to get help from, 4) uses a hosted solution or not

Comment: @SunilD. I feel comfortable using Flash and AS3 and most of these server provide support for flash (correct me if i am wrong). but which one would be most easy to understand for me (I do know Java and AS3 some php and very very basic concepts of c++ and c#) Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my recent post to the question you referenced above. It was added a few minutes ago. It might have some good insights..

[AS3:Multiplayer Game by using AS3 with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691784/as3multiplayer-game-by-using-as3-with-php/14694337#14694337)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Smartfox, which you suggest, is not free. Which one among the free client-server would you suggest? Thanks again

Comment: My apologies i missed the "free" requirement :). I would say its hard to tell. Red5 is supposed to be pretty "equivalent" to Flash Media Server... but I will say, that you will be hard pressed to find a free solution that is suitable for production high-scale environment. If you have a low traffic expectancy, almost all of the above solutions could/will work for your needs. I don't know much about Spogg.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not going to have a high traffic on my website, maximum at any given moment would be about 4-6. But mostly it  will be 1 or 2 people against each other or against AI. Which one would be easiest to implement in your opinion? Also, I accepted your answer. Cheers.

Comment: Since scalability is a non-issue, AMFPHP is a great start. If you don't go with a solution that targets multiplayer functionality (such as RED5, FMS, or SmartFox), you'll have to write the packet replication yourself, but thats not to hard to do for a simple case. Also, if this is not a commercial product and you aren't charging for access, you can use the free version of SmartFox 2, just download it, install it, and play. We did a multiplayer demo with the free SmartFox and we had 10 people playing in the same room, working pretty well. Hope that points you in a good direction!